# OpenCV - Concave hull

Tags: opencv, concave-hull

I am looking for an OpenCV implementation of a function to find the concave hull of a set of points (as for the convexHull function). Does anyone know of it?

Here is an explanation: http://ubicomp.algoritmi.uminho.pt/local/concavehull.html

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is there a definition of a concave hull? i think it's quite ambiguous and you need some heuristic... one solution could be "active contour model" aka "snakes" which had an implementation in openCV in some earlier versions, but i am not sure whether it still exists in the current version.

Comment: A [Java implementation](http://www.geosensor.net/phpws/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=13) can be seen here. Perhaps you can convert it to what language you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Growing Neural Gas algorithm.

There are several implementations in web take a look at ( https://github.com/BelBES/libGNG ) for example.

Video of the algorithm is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVd4ly8wilY

Very interesting java applet here:

Also take a look at this site: http://www.demogng.de/