# Concave hulls/contours with opencv?

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, robotics

Does opencv feature the capability of extracting concave hulls/contours from a set of 2D points?

Also, is there a possibility to extract all possible hulls satisfying a certain criterion; let say all hulls must have their areas bounded  `(min<area<max)` ?

Comment: Same question was asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939172/opencv-concave-hull, see if the answer given helps you. Seems pretty hard task, good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the excellent [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org) which (by its very nature) has to handle concave hulls in both 2D and 3D. As a library, it can integrate quite nicely with OpenCV (if that's what you need).

In particular, [this example](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/hull_2d.php) which show-cases the [`pcl::ConcaveHull`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_concave_hull.html) class. The [`cropHull`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_crop_hull.html) operation might prove useful, in response to your second question.

(Notice that in fact this is actually underpinned by the "grand-daddy" of hull libraries - [qhull](http://www.qhull.org)).

Comment: which is a shit library that crashes if you use openmp on it (qhull)